# bad_allock error in trying to read large file in qt

Tags: qt, qt4

How to read bigger than 600mb file in qt? 
I am trying to read file using file.readAll(). It works small files. but it gives bad_alloc error in large files? what should I do?

Comment: Please specify which platform you're doing this on.

Comment: Can I ask what is going to happen when you have loaded 600Mb of data - I hope it's not for the user to manipulate or navigate as it's surely going to be hopelessly inefficient for any user related interaction. Problems related to loading large files nearly always point to a need to solve a different problem so as to prevent getting into a deeper and deeper hole over time. Divide and conquer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't do it.**

It's rarely necessary to load a huge file into memory in one operation.

You can't be loading this much information for user navigation or manipulation, so if, as I suspect, you are simply acting as an intermediary between having the file on disc and sending the file somewhere else then use a mechanism which treats the Qfile as a **QIODevice** instead of loading it all completely as a QString or QByteArray.

If you (or your customers) are on Windows using a 32 bit system but are likely to have more than 2Gb of RAM at your disposal, you might want to be aware of the [/LARGEADDRESSAWARE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz223b1z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) linker option which will allow you to support addresses larger than 2Gb and which *may* also improve your situation if you are truly unable to do without loading the file into memory.

Comment: Hi Roger Attrill. Actually I want to read whole file and upload to server. I trying to develop uploader(client to server). I considered to read file in chunks. But QNetworkAccessManager doesnt provide chunked transfer.

Comment: [QNetworkAccessManager::post](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#post) has a QIODevice option in addition to the QByteArray version - doesn't that avoid loading the file first?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl,--large-address-aware
```

to your qt pro file, from what I understand it will allow a process to accumulate more memory than 2GB.

Comment: Yes, but only on x64 Windows. And assuming MinGW is used.

Answer (score 1):

Consider reading the file in chunks, instead of not all at once. Of course, your goal might be to display the entire file in a text editor, in which case loading it partially is more complicated. You're being very vague, so it's hard to be more specific.